# C# /.net /DataGrid / iTextSharp -- I have a bit of a long one, ill explain

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Hello there thank you for taking your time to read here, here is my problem, I am making a Winforms app that pulls all relevant data pertaining to invoices to a temp db C# then pulls that into a Datagrid with no issues, I can call the Datagrid into my pdf no issues there either, where I have an issue is that for each row in the data grid I need to dynamically add a cell to a pdf and populate the unique item info to those cells which are part of the same invoice, for a clearer example

tranlinenum 1 is item A
tranlinenum 2 is item B and
tranlinenum 3 is Item C

I can get the pdf to dynamically create each cell/row for each item but the info displayed in those said cells and rows are not for that item, they are for the first one that is pulled through

===========Here is the start of my Code===============

```
string lineNumberInput = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
string itemCodeInput = dt.Rows[0][12].ToString();
string itemNameInput = dt.Rows[0][13].ToString();
string QtyInput = dt.Rows[0][14].ToString();
string UnitPriceInput = dt.Rows[0][15].ToString();
//string Discount = dt.Rows[0][""].ToString();
string lineTotalInput = dt.Rows[0][16].ToString();
string wasReturnedInput = dt.Rows[0][17].ToString();


foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
{

var Cell_LineNumberList = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lineNumberInput, 
tablefont));
var Cell_ItemCodelist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(itemCodeInput, tablefont));
var Cell_ItemNamelist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(itemNameInput, tablefont));
var Cell_Qtylist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(QtyInput, tablefont));
var Cell_UnitPricelist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(UnitPriceInput, tablefont));
var Cell_Discountlist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("None", tablefont));
var Cell_LineTotallist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lineTotalInput, tablefont));
var Cell_WasReturnedlist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(wasReturnedInput, 
tablefont));

t.AddCell(Cell_LineNumberList);
t.AddCell(Cell_ItemCodelist);
t.AddCell(Cell_ItemNamelist);
t.AddCell(Cell_Qtylist);
t.AddCell(Cell_UnitPricelist);
t.AddCell(Cell_Discountlist);
t.AddCell(Cell_LineTotallist);
t.AddCell(Cell_WasReturnedlist);

}
```

I have also attached a screenshot of the invoice an how the part looks in question

https://prnt.sc/qr5lcy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the values returned by the query just once, for row[0]

Just move the code above the foreach within the foreach, accessing each dataRow, i.e

```
string lineNumberInput = dataRow[1].ToString();
```

instead of

```
string lineNumberInput = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Comment: You are the GOAT, thank you for your help, solved it exactly as desired, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your vars such as `lineNumberInput` in every loop iteration. Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
{
  string lineNumberInput = dataRow[1].ToString();
  string itemCodeInput = dataRow[12].ToString();
  string itemNameInput = dataRow[13].ToString();
  string QtyInput = dataRow[14].ToString();
  string UnitPriceInput = dataRow[15].ToString();
  //string Discount = dataRow[""].ToString();
  string lineTotalInput = dataRow[16].ToString();
  string wasReturnedInput = dataRow[17].ToString();

  var Cell_LineNumberList = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lineNumberInput, 
tablefont));
  var Cell_ItemCodelist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(itemCodeInput, tablefont));
  var Cell_ItemNamelist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(itemNameInput, tablefont));
  var Cell_Qtylist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(QtyInput, tablefont));
  var Cell_UnitPricelist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(UnitPriceInput, tablefont));
  var Cell_Discountlist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("None", tablefont));
  var Cell_LineTotallist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lineTotalInput, tablefont));
  var Cell_WasReturnedlist = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(wasReturnedInput, 
tablefont));

  t.AddCell(Cell_LineNumberList);
  t.AddCell(Cell_ItemCodelist);
  t.AddCell(Cell_ItemNamelist);
  t.AddCell(Cell_Qtylist);
  t.AddCell(Cell_UnitPricelist);
  t.AddCell(Cell_Discountlist);
  t.AddCell(Cell_LineTotallist);
  t.AddCell(Cell_WasReturnedlist);

}
```

Comment: thank you for your help aswell, marked both as answer as both are the are correct solution